# ggpairs change axisLabel font size

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, ggally

When plotting internal `axisLabels` for `ggpairs`, if numbers are large, they get cropped off.

```
fakedata <- data.frame(Var1=rnorm(500, 3, 6), 
                       Var2=runif(500, 0, 5500), 
                       Var3=rpois(500, 6), 
                       Var4=rpois(500, 1500),
                       Var5=runif(500, 1, 60))

ggpairs(fakedata, axisLabels= "internal")
```

[image]

In the graph above, the y-axis labels for Var2 are cut off, and the x-axis numbers for Var4 run together. How would I change the font size?

I've seen from [this page](https://github.com/ggobi/ggally/issues/6) that it may be possible to find a fix by adding `theme()` from `ggplot2`, but I can't find a theme element that would represent font size for axis text.

Comment: Let's try `help("wrap", package = "GGally")`

Comment: @crayfish44; can you show how to do this please. I have tried `ggpairs(fakedata, axisLabels= "none", diag=list(continuous=wrap("diagAxis", gridLabelSize=3)))`, which changes the size, but `hjust` seems to be hard-coded, which it seems ro me is the parameter to be changed for the y-axis labels

Comment: @user20650; I'd taken what OP wants that changing font size, so I inducted the method of using `ggally_xxx`. I know only `diag=list(continuous=wrap(ggally_diagAxis, ~ ))` and it is equivalent to what you say. I would have been comment it to save OP time and doesn't expect too much. Thank you for letting me realise the idea isn't enought to solve this question and so on.

Comment: Thanks @crayfish44, I thought I was missing something obvious. So  I guess the answer is to tweak ggally_diagAxis function, to allow for custom text justification, and use that instead.